# CodeDom reference added properly, dll file is not

Tags: c#, reference, codedom

This has caused me a day's worth of work at this point. In visual studio I can add a reference to a custom-made .dll file. Once the reference has been added, I can call the .dll file:

```
someClass_inDll sc = new someClass_inDll();
sc.someVoid_in_dll();
```

Simple, right? No assembly use, invoking etc. needs to be done. I would like to be able to do this *exact* same thing using CodeDom! So, assume I have a custom .dll file (already made and on my hard drive), I have been adding the *full* path to said dll file to the list of codedom references. However, the actual .dll file is not being compiled with my project (as it is with visual Studio).

Can someone please tell me why this is? It's making no sense to me what so ever.

I do ***NOT*** want to add the .dll file as an embedded resource because the only way I could call functions in the dll file would be to invoke it which is something I'd rather not do for personal reasons.

I really appreciate the help everyone!

Thanks,
Evan

Comment: Are you saying that your project, which uses a codedom code provider, is not a visual studio project itself?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the executable being generated through CodeDom does not seem to have the .dll built into it (thus rendering the dll file unusable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but here goes...

Visual Studio is copying all of your references into the output directory that are set to "Copy Local" in your .proj file AFTER compilation.  The compiler itself is not concerned with the deployment of your dependencies, this is what msbuild is for.

So, when you add a reference to the CompilerParameters of your provider, it will use the reference to build the executable, but you will have to copy it yourself.

Comment: Okay, so in CodeDom I add the reference to the FULL path of the dll file I would like to use. Then, once the executable has been compiled with the appropriate reference I should copy the dll from its full path to the path of the compiled CodeDom executable?

Comment: Right, they need to be in the same directory.

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: Add your referenced DLL location to the system path or use the GAC.

Comment: I've heard of the GAC - never had any luck with it though. What exactly do you mean by "add the dll location to the system path"? For some reason I'm not having much luck finding these things through SE's.

Comment: I mean that you could require that the machine running your CodeDOM compiled executables have it's PATH environment variable set to include the directory of any non-standard dlls (such as your's) it needs.  Dll's in PATH directories will be located without having to copy them.